# CSS counter-increment not incrementing

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following HTML markup

```
<h1>Article title</h1>
<h2>First section</h2>
<h3>First section, first subsection</h3>
<h2>Second section</h2>
<h2>Third section</h2>
<h3>Third section, first subsection</h3>
<h2>Fourth section</h2>
<h2>Fifth section</h2>
<h3>Fifth section, first subsection</h3>
<h3>Fifth section, second subsection</h3>
<h3>Fifth section, third subsection</h3>
...
```

And the following SCSS

```
body.page-id-4065 {
    counter-reset: h2;

    h2 { counter-reset: h3; }
    h3 { counter-reset: h4; }
    h4 { counter-reset: h5; }
    h5 { counter-reset: h6; }

    h2:before {color: $grey-dark; counter-increment: h2; content: counter(h2) ". "}
    h3:before {color: $grey-dark; counter-increment: h3; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) ". "}
    h4:before {color: $grey-dark; counter-increment: h4; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) ". "}
    h5:before {color: $grey-dark; counter-increment: h5; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) ". "}
    h6:before {color: $grey-dark; counter-increment: h6; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) "." counter(h6) ". "}

    h2.nocount:before, h3.nocount:before, h4.nocount:before, h5.nocount:before, h6.nocount:before { content: ""; counter-increment: none }

    #reply-title:before { content: ''; }
}
```

It seems the increment is working fine outputting:

> 1. First section
>      1.1. First section, first subsection
> 2. Second section
> 3. Third section
>      3.1. Third section, first subsection
> 4. Fourth section
> 5. Fifth section

But when it gets there those several H3s are displayed without a counter increment as:

> 5.1. First subsection
>   5.1. Second subsection
>   5.1. Third subsection

I can't seem to grasp why it isn't incrementing those sub but works ok on the top level ones. Any idea why this may be happening?

If you want to see the live page (scroll down to heading #5): https://www.melopienso.com/blog/perros/comida/pienso/

Thanks!

P.S: I've researched other very similar posts on StackOverflow without success for this particular case.

Comment: Well, when I put your exact SCSS in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/2gL25jd3/1/), it works as expected, so it might have something to do with CSS you're not showing here. Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: The site you link to doesn't count, since 1) it isn't minimal; it includes many stylesheets and scripts etc, and 2) since it's apparently a work in progress, we are looking at a moving target: it may change at any minute while we're looking at it!

Comment: I'm sorry it looks like a work in progress, because it isn't (apart from adding a few more images). As the problem may be with the particular configuration of scripts and stylesheets, I don't know how to produce a minimal, complete and verifiable example.
Thanks for stopping by!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because the `h2` is in a sub-level (it has a parent that `h3` doesn't).

This works:

```
<div> <!-- h2's first parent - also h3's first parent -->
  <h2>Fifth section</h2>
  <h3>Fifth section, first subsection</h3>
  <h3>Fifth section, first subsection</h3>
</div>
```

This works:

```
<div> <!-- h2's first parent - h3's parent (not first) -->
  <h2>Fifth section</h2>

  <div>
    <h3>Fifth section, first subsection</h3>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Fifth section, first subsection</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't:

```
<div>
  <div> <!-- h2's first parent - wait, there's no h3s in sub-levels! -->
    <h2>Fifth section</h2>
  </div>

  <h3>Fifth section, first subsection</h3>
  <h3>Fifth section, first subsection</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately it seems that my page builder can't handle that, as it wraps every element within several layers of divs, so the H2 is always in a div and the H3 are always on their own div at the same level. I'm starting to get sooo sick of these builders... Thank you very much for bringing some clarity. It was driving me mad.